# JavaScript: Comparing characters and accented characters

Tags: javascript, string, diacritics

I'm creating a simple hang man like game. The user can input a "secret sentence" and then the players have to guess it by chosing letters one by one.

Since this game will be used in several languages, I would like to solve all accented character if a player chose the non-accented character. For example:

```
IL CANE È BELLO.
```

If the player choses the vowel "e" only the vowels without accent will be solved (the game compares characters with ===). Instead I would like that the game recognizes automatically all chars accented or not (è, é, e...)

I'm about to torture myself writing a function that checks every accented character, but I was wondering if ther might be an easier way.

This is what my funciton look like so far (I just added the è accented vowel)

```
function isAccentedVowel(chosenChar, currentChar) {
    console.log('The user selected this char: ' + chosenChar)
    console.log('I\'m comparing it to this char: ' + currentChar)
    switch (chosenChar) {
        case 'E':
            if (currentChar === 'È') return true;
    }
}
```

note: the secret sentence and every character are uppercase

Comment: Maybe look at using .charCodeAt() see:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624379/how-to-convert-letters-to-numbers-with-javascript , I suspect that those accented characters will fall between a number range, which you may be able to use. Not sure though. Also check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Strategy pattern is your friend. You select the strategy based on user locale. This way your code stays clean, instead of having a kilometer long switch statement

Comment: You can also use lodash.deburr before comparing, see here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#deburr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) to compare the accented characters with their normal counterpart.

To perform comparison, you need to first get/extract normal character from accented character as below.

```
string.normalize('NFD')
```

This will return an array containing two items. You can now compare the first item in the array with normal characters.

```js
function isAccented(char, accentedChar) {
  return char === accentedChar.normalize('NFD')[0];
}

console.log(isAccented('E', 'È'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `sensitivity` value of *"base"*. This has the added bonus of comparing case-insensitively (which I assume you'll also want).

If your characters match, `localeCompare()` returns `0`.

Here's an example based on the assumption that you'll want to find the positions of the matching characters (ie, a *"hang man"* game)

```js
const locale = undefined // set this if it matters, otherwise use default
const options = { sensitivity: 'base' }

const findCharPositions = (str, char) => 
  Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, (indexes, c, i) =>
    (c.localeCompare(char, locale, options) || indexes.push(i), indexes), [])

const str = 'IL CANE È BELLO'
console.log('Find "l":', findCharPositions(str, 'l'))
console.log('Find "e":', findCharPositions(str, 'e'))
```