# Converting nested loops into forEach();

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

Im trying to learn forEach() method but i cant find more advanced examples. So i thought about refactoring my Codewars code to learn from it. I dont know know to properly use forEach method in nested loops. Hope You can help me learn from this example :)

6 kyu - Replace With Alphabet Position
https://www.codewars.com/kata/546f922b54af40e1e90001da/train/javascript

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    let textToArray = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi,'').toUpperCase().split(''); //Eliminate anything thats not a letter 
    const alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    let pointsHolder = [];                            //empty array for score
    for (let i = 0; i < textToArray.length; i++){
        for  (let j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
            if (textToArray[i] == alphabet[j] ) {     //We check the index of given string letter in alphabet
                pointsHolder.push(j+1)                //give it a score based on place in alphabet(+1 for 0 as 1st index)
            }
        }
    }
    return pointsHolder.join(' ');                    //return scored array as a string with spaces
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: @Terry's solution is still the more efficient solution to your code challenge)

You can replace it in the following way:

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  let textToArray = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gi, '').toUpperCase().split(''); 
  const alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  let pointsHolder = []; 
  textToArray.forEach(t2a => {
    alphabet.forEach((a, j) => {
      if (t2a == a) { pointsHolder.push(j + 1) }
    })
  })
  return pointsHolder.join(' '); 
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("ABCSTU"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to use a nested loop, which is computationally expensive. With that, you also don't have to manually create an A-Z array.

You can easily [convert alphabets to any arbitrary number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624379/how-to-convert-letters-to-numbers-with-javascript) using [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). `a` has a character code of 97, `b` has a character code of 98, and etc... to get a one-based index (a=1, b=2, ...) you jus t need to subtract 96 from the number.

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabets = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '').split('');
  return alphabets.map(alphabet => alphabet.charCodeAt(0) - 96).join(' ');
}
```

Alternatively you can also use a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), but that requires storing the array in yet another variable before returning it:

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabets = text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
  
  const codes = [];
  for (const alphabet of alphabets) {
    codes.push(alphabet.charCodeAt() - 96);
  }
  
  return codes.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `charCode` solution proposed in [Terry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093285/13762301) but which also avoids nested loops is be to create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the characters you want to score against and then access it per character from the passed string.

Keep in mind that [strings are iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#iterating_over_a_string) without needing to convert to an array.

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  text = text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, '');

  const alphabet = new Map(
    ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
      .map((v, i) => [v, i + 1])
  );

  const pointsHolder = [];
  for (const char of text) {
    pointsHolder.push(alphabet.get(char))
  }

  return pointsHolder.join(' ');
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("ABCSTU"))
```

This also allows you to use a Map which doesn't necessarily have consecutive charCodes

```js
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  text = text.toUpperCase().replace(/[^]/gi, '');

  const alphabet = new Map(
    ["", "", ""]
      .map((v, i) => [v, i + 1])
  );

  const pointsHolder = [];
  for (const char of text) {
    pointsHolder.push(alphabet.get(char))
  }

  return pointsHolder.join(' ');
}

console.log(alphabetPosition("ABCSTU"))
```